# Log output of multiple test cases in xml with gtest

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I am executing this command :

__run_unit_tests --gtest_output=xml:my.xml --gtest_filter=TestSuite1.TestCase1 arg1 arg2

__run_unit_tests --gtest_output=xml:my.xml --gtest_filter=TestSuite1.TestCase2 arg1

I am running above two commands on console, with different number of arguments for each testcase. But my xml file is being overwritten with results for each test case, i.e. i just have entry for last run testcase. How to correct this? What should i do considering the fact different testcase may have different number of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

By passing different arguments in each case you are in fact running different
tests. Therefore write the xml reports to different files. It may be helpful
to adopt a convention for encoding the variable arguments into the filename of
the xml report.

If you do not want to do that, then instead of writing one test case that
you run with N different arguments sets, write N test cases each of which
you run with 0 arguments, and write the xml report of each to its own xml file.